# Bootstrap3 Icons how align icon on center in div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Code:

```
<div class="input">
<div class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;</div>
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" placeholder="Login">
</div>
```

In result we have:

[image]

Tell me please how make **in my code** that icon will be in center white block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.input .icon {padding: 7px 7px;}
```

Set padding what you need and only.

Enjoy)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Adjust % accordingly.

```
.input .icon { 
    display: block; 
    width: 50%; 
    margin: auto; 
}
```

Another option would be

```
.input { text-align: center; }

.icon { display: inline-block; padding-top: 10px; }
```